# Pandas: Filter rows by comparing a column's value to another value for the same column in a different row

Tags: pandas

I have searched the heck out of this one, and I don't think I've found anything applicable. But I'm new to Pandas, so I may have missed something-apologies in this case.

Suppose I have a dataframe, df, with  the following contents:

```
Column1       Column2
A             Apple     
B             Apple     
A             Pear      
A             Orange    
B             Orange    
A             Pear
```

I want to filter the dataframe to show ONLY rows where:

-Column2's value matches at least 1 other Column2 value
-For these 2 matching rows, at least 1 of Column1's values are different.

Expected results of the above df:

```
Column1       Column2 
A             Apple    
B             Apple 
A             Orange 
B             Orange
```

I have tried using the .loc() method for this, but I cannot find an appropriate filter/set of filters. (I also tried to use a 'for i in df' loop, but this just gave an error).

I would usually post some sample code in these situations, but I don't think any of my approaches so far have made much sense.

Any help would be much appreciated-thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `nunqiue`:

```
df_filtered = df[df.groupby('Column2')['Column1'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
print(df_filtered)
```

We could also use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df[df['Column2'].map(pd.crosstab(df['Column1'],df['Column2']).gt(0).sum().gt(1))]
#df[df['Column2'].map(pd.crosstab(df['Column1'],df['Column2']).where(lambda x: x>0).count().gt(1))]
```

We coluld also use [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) **in general this is slower**

```
df.groupby('Column2').filter(lambda x: x.Column1.nunique()>1)
```

**Output**

```
  Column1 Column2
0       A   Apple
1       B   Apple
3       A  Orange
4       B  Orange
```

---

**The best solution is the first with [groupby.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)**

Comment: Thanks. The groupby.transform() method worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a groupby and filter:

```
(
    df.groupby('Column2')
    .filter(lambda x: len(x.drop_duplicates(subset='Column1'))>1)
)


Column1 Column2
0   A   Apple
1   B   Apple
3   A   Orange
4   B   Orange
```

Comment: we can use `groupby.filter` the bad thing about this method is that it is slower,
on the other hand if you include drop_dupicates it is much slower